# What is the particle “irgend” used for, or what concept/sentiment does it convey?

Tags: translation, adverb, pronoun, particle, indefinite-pronoun

I wonder what *irgend* means? I’ve seen so many words with it as a prefix, like [irgendein](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/irgendein), [irgendwas](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/irgendwas) and [irgendwo](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/irgendwo). What do they have in common that *irgend* expresses?

The explanations in the Duden partly reference each other — it doesn’t help much to know that *irgendwo* means *an irgendeinem Ort* when you also don’t understand *irgendein*.

Comment: You’re trying to sneak around the potential closing of the other question by asking for the differences between *irgendeine* and *einige* **again.** *Please* look up the two in a German-English dictionary. Yes, they both translate to *some* (among others) but the issue here is that you don’t realise the meanings *some* can have. The rest of the question is valid, though.

Comment: Also... you linked to my article. What's left unclear? Did you read it all? Because skimming will not do it.

Comment: You guys are 0 help.

Comment: We’re trying to help, only you’re not accepting our suggestions to help you.

Comment: Look man, this is not Reddit where you just throw a question out there and answers pour in. This is a site that aims at having well worked out questions that include a problem, why it's a problem and possibly how the attempts at solving it so far have failed. You may or may not like the format but that's how it is. I think you don't like it because you're putting very little effort into your questions and you are not really willing to address concerns or questions people ask you in the comments. That's fine....

Comment: ... but then this is simply not the site you need. But you have no right to be dismissive the way you are.  Instead of just heading over to Reddit or wherever you feel like you need to lash out a bit for not getting the result you wanted. Well, guess what. You didn't get it because you didn't pay your dues. If you got zero help here then you and only you are responsible. Why am I rambling about this? Because I'm tired of people who think we're just answering machines, there at your pleasure. We even tried to help you in the comments so show some respect.

Comment: @Jan I would strongly suggest to the OP to delete the second part of the question (or at least the first part of the second part). As you say, the rest of the question *is valid*, and in fact it has an easy answer that should be given here. ("irgend" -> "no matter who/which/what/where/...").

Comment: @Zach I took the burden to rephrase your question to demonstrate to you and other visitors what our expectations about valid questions are. I hope it will get enough re-open votes now. Nevertheless I strongly recommend that you read and try profoundly to understand Emanuel's comments.

Comment: @Zach Seeing that this is your 6th question here and that 4 of them apparently got answers that were upvoted multiple times by other users, I would like to remind you that you have the possibility to _accept_ an answer by clicking on the green mark on its left side. This gives a bonus of 15rep to the author and 2rep to you, and it tells other visitors that this was the answer that you took the most benefit out of. You can read more about it here: http://german.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 11):

Irgend is used to reinforce uncertainty similar to some/any.

Examples

> Hat irgendwer meine Tasche gesehen?
>
> Has anyone seen my bag?

---

> Kannst du es irgendwo sehen?
>
> Can you see it anywhere?

---

> Sie suchen irgendwas.
>
> They're looking for something.

---

Regarding the differences you're interested in:

irgendwas and etwas are synonyms. like the example above could also be written as:

> Sie suchen etwas.

Irgendeine and einige however are quite different. Einige is used for small groups.
Example:

> Es gibt einige mögliche Übersetzungen.
>
> There are several possible translations.

Irgendeine, as said at the beginning, just expresses uncertainty.
Example:

> Gibt es irgendeine Lösung?
>
> Is there any solution?

Answer (score 10):

Most of the time, *irgend-* corresponds to *no matter who/which/where/how/...*
or *I don't know the details*.

E. g.,

- irgendjemand, irgendwer -> some/any person (I don't know or don't care who)
- irgendwo -> at some/any place, no matter where
- irgendein Auto -> some/any car, no matter which one
- irgendwelche Insekten -> some/any insects, no matter which kind
- irgendwas, irgendetwas -> something (I don't know what)

Note that *irgend-* is sometimes redundant.
There is no fundamental difference
between *Hat jemand angerufen* and *Hat irgendjemand angerufen*
or between *Hast du ein Taxi gesehen* and *Hast du irgendein Taxi gesehen*;
*irgend-* just stresses the idea of "I don't care who/which" which is
already expressed in the base word.

Comment: Or "Have you seen any taxi at all?"

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Of course, "at all" is redundant as well.