# „Kein“ und dessen Verwendung in negierten Sätzen

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, negation

Was ist in deisem Satz eigentlich falsch?

> Lotte kann den Namen in irgendeinem Verzeichnis nicht finden.

Es ist ja das Finden, dass nicht wird.

> Lotte kann den Namen in keinem Verzeichnis finden.

wäre, soweit ich verstanden habe, richtig. Warum denn? Lotte hat doch viele Verzeichnisse durchsucht und daher sollte ja nicht *Verzeichnis* negiert werden, sondern *finden*, oder?

Wenn ich das Negieren von *finden* betonen möchte könnte ich vielleicht

> Lotte kann den Namen nicht finden, und zwar in keinem Verzeichnis.

schreiben. Eine umständliche Umschreibung, könnte man behaupten.

In Englisch könnte man wohl unmöglich sagen:

> Lotte can find the name in *none* of the lists.

eher

> Lotte can’t find the name in *any* list.

wäre richtig.

Offenbar ist das zwischen den Sprachen verschieden, worüber man sich auch nicht erstaunen muss.

Meine Frage: Ist mein erstes Beispiel oder eine Variante davon ganz unmöglich?

Comment: Die Sprachen sind eben verschieden, so dass einiges nicht direkr übernommen werden kann. Eine Möglichkeit es ähnlich kurz zu machen ware vielleicht "Lotte war es unmöglich, den Namen in irgendeinem Verzeichnis zu finden."

Comment: Es wird nicht das Finden in einem Verzeichnis negiert, sondern in allen. Es in irgendeinem nicht zu finden kann auch bedeuten, dass sie es in 9 von 10 Verzeichnissen gefunden hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kurz vorneweg: Das *irgend…* deutet praktisch immer auf *irgend*eine Form von Beliebigkeit oder Unsicherheit hin – mehr dazu steht z.B. unter [What is the particle “irgend” used for, or what concept/sentiment does it convey?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/what-is-the-particle-irgend-used-for-or-what-concept-sentiment-does-it-convey). In diesem Fall könnte man es wohl weglassen, um den Kern der Frage hervorzuheben, und ohne die Bedeutung des Satzes stark zu verfälschen.

Und die unterscheidliche Bedeutung der Sätze

> Lotte kann den Namen in einem Verzeichnis nicht finden.
>   Lotte kann den Namen in keinem Verzeichnis finden.

(die auch schon Ludi in seiner Antwort betont hat) gibt es entsprechend auch im Englischen:

> Lotte can’t find the name in one list.
>   Lotte can’t find the name in any list.

---

Aber falls ich das richtig verstanden habe, war die eigentliche Frage ja, warum sich im ersten Satz die Negation eindeutig auf das *Finden* bezieht (*nicht finden*), während sie sich im zweiten Satz auf die Verzeichnisse zu beziehen scheint (*keinem Verzeichnis*).

Eine zufriedenstellende Antwort darauf gibt es vermutlich nicht. Ein Satz wie

> Lotte kann den Namen in allen Verzeichnissen nicht finden.

wäre zwar grammatikalisch korrekt, aber hört sich ebenso seltsam an wie

> Lotte can find the name in none of the lists

(Man könnte umgekehrt fragen, wie man denn im Englischen einen Satz formulieren könnte, bei dem sich die Negation auf die Verzeichnisse bezieht – und ein anderer Satz als dieser fiele mir da jetzt nicht ein …)

Answer (score 4):

Nichts ist daran falsch. Es ändert sich lediglich die Bedeutung - und zwar in gravierender Weise! Stellen Sie sich folgende Unterhaltung vor

- Lotte: Herr Stein, ich kann den Namen im Weber-Verzeichnis nicht finden. 
  Ich glaube nicht, dass es sich um einen von Webers Kunden handelt!
- Herr Stein: Such mal unter seinem Alias!
- Frau Stein: Wo, brennt's, Jutta!
- Jutta: Ach, Lotte kann den Namen in irgendeinem Verzeichnis nicht finden. Jetzt nervt sie Ihren Gatten ständig damit.

Bei *irgendeinem* Verzeichnis handelt es sich hier also um ein *ganz bestimmtes*, entweder unbekanntes, oder absichtlich ungenannt gelassenes Verzeichnis! Im Englischen wäre das:

> Lotte can't find the name in some list. Now she's constantly pestering your spouse about it!

Comment: In der nächsten Folge: Am Schreibtisch sitzend zeigt Herr Stein Lotte, wie man richtig in Verzeichnissen sucht. Lotte lässt aus Versehen den Kugelschreiber fallen und kriecht unter den Schreibtisch, um ihn zu suchen. In diesem Augenblick kommt plötzlich Frau Stein zur Tür herein…

Answer (score 1):

Wie Ludi schon angedeutet hat, haben die beiden Sätze verschiedene Bedeutungen, je nachdem *welcher* Satzteil negiert wird.

> Lotte kann den Namen in irgendeinem Verzeichnis nicht finden.

*Nicht* bezieht sich direkt auf finden. Lässt man es weg, erhält man einen mit umgekehrter aber sonst identischer Bedeutung:

> Lotte kann den Namen in irgendeinem Verzeichnis finden.

*Irgendein Verzeichnis* ist ein zufällig ausgewähltes Verzeichnis aus einer Gruppe. In einem von diesen Verzeichnissen kann Lotte den Namen finden. In dem entsprechend negierten Satz kann Lotte den Namen nicht *in genau diesem Verzeichnis* finden.

---

> Lotte kann den Namen in keinem Verzeichnis finden.

Im Grunde ist dies eine positive Aussage (»Lotte kann etwas finden«), mit dem Zusatz *in keinem Verzeichnis* — die Negation bezieht sich also ausschließlich auf die Verzeichnisse. Das Gegenteil wäre:

> Lotte kann den Namen in allen Verzeichnissen finden.

Lotte kann also, sooft sie möchte, *irgendein* Verzeichnis aufmachen und wird den Namen dort *nicht* finden.

---

In Dialekten, besonders im Bairischen, muss auch noch doppelte und dreifache Verneinung beachtet werden. Der erste Satz wäre:

> De Lotte ko den Nama in am Vazeichnis ned findn.

Man beachte die einfache Verneinung; es geht nur um ein Verzeichnis. Der zweite Satz hingegen wäre:

> De Lotte ko den Nama in koam Vazeichnis ned findn.

Sowohl das Verzeichnis wie auch das Verb sind negiert, es ist also nirgendwo möglich, den Namen zu finden.

---

Zum vollständigen Verständnis von *kein*, ein Gespräch in einem Laden in der DDR:

> Gibts hier keine Hosen?
>
> Keine Hosen gibts im zweiten Stock. Hier gibts keine Mäntel.

(Credits to [Hendrik Vogt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/nicht-vs-kein#comment2884_1103).)